# Dealing with Exceptions,Errors discussion and explanation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, error-handling

I have read various topics about **Exceptions**, **Errors**, **Error Codes** etc. 
I've searched an answer through stackoverflow's questions, but I still have some misunderstandings...
So while reading my question please lets think more about delivering better results to the customer, instead of following "theoretical" patterns which may not work in a true life scenario. So Let's go:

Some specifications, to add transparency to our situation:

1. 3 Layers (DataAccess -> Service -> UI)
2. Repository Pattern
3. ORM - NHibernate
4. IoC - Castle Windsor
5. User Interface Framework - ASP.NET MVC3

**The scenario:**

Suppose we have a service interface:

```
public interface IProductService
{
    // Just get the products from DB
    IList<Products> GetAllProducts();

    // Makes a conversion between product's current UM and requested 'toUnitMeasure'
    double ConvertUnitMeasureTo(Product product, UnitMeasure toUnitMeasure);
}
```

Now lets analyze what things may happen, for the both methods:

1. `GetAllProducts();` :

   - The resulted list could be empty.
   - The DB may throw an `SqlException`.
2. `ConvertUnitMeasureTo(Product product, UnitMeasure toUnitMeasure);` :

   - The `product` might be not found in the DB.
   - The `toUnitMeasure` might be not found either.
   - `product`'s current unit measure might not be convertible to `toUnitMeasure` (eg: MASS to LENGTH)
   - some sort of `ArithmeticException`'s etc.

Ok so far so good. Lets take a look at the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ProductViewModel model) 
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // At this point, some of the (above enumerated) situations may occur.
        // Some of them are Exceptions while another
        // are unpleasant but 'expected' situations.
        var result = _productService.ConvertToUnitMeasure(model.Product, model.UnitMeasure);
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:**

How to treat all those situations inside the `Controller`? while:

- Delivering a (localized) answer to the client.(eg: HardCoding the message inside a `CustomException.Message`, is not suited for my case)
- Being able to distinguish each situation that may occur, in order to take a specific action for it (eg: if `The toUnitMeasure might be not found either.` to make an `RedirectToAction("CreateUnitMeasure","UnitMeasure")`);
- Keeping the `Controller` 'thin' as possible. Eg: Avoid to implement the conversion  method inside the `Controller`, instead of the **Service Layer**, through separating the `ConvertUnitMeasureTo(..)` into smaller service methods. *(hope no explanation needed)*

Your answer is valuable for me so please do not hesitate to express yourself.Thank you very much for attention.